# ConcurrentHashMap put vs putIfAbsent

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, hashmap

Java [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29) says that, `putIfAbsent` is equivalent to

```
   if (!map.containsKey(key)) 
      return map.put(key, value);
   else
      return map.get(key);
```

So if the key exists in the map, it doesn't update its value. Is this correct?

What if i want to update a keys value based on some criteria? Say expiration time etc.

Would this be a better impl for adding and updating cache?

```
public void AddToCache(T key, V value)
{
   V local = _cache.putifabsent(key, value);

   if(local.equals(value) && local.IsExpired() == false){
     return;
   }
   // this is for updating the cache with a new value
   _cache.put(key, value);
}
```

Comment: @Gray second line in the equiv. code saying  that if the key is not in the cache, then put it , otherwise just return the value. it doesnt update the value if key value pair is already in the cache.

Comment: your logic is a bit hosed though. if `local` is equal to `value` then you just updated the map. Don't you mean if it's *not* equal to `value` ? Meaning there was something already in the map?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry.  You are using the word "update" to mean not create.  You are correct, sorry.

Comment: Be very careful about the semantics of that snippet in Javadoc -- it always returns the **previous** value under that key.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So it doesnt update a key's value. is this correct?

That is correct.  It will return the current value that was already in the Map.

> would this be a better impl for adding and updating cache?

A couple things would make your implementation better.

**1.** You shouldn't use putIfAbsent to test if it exists, you should only use it when you want to ensure if one does not exist then `putIfAbsent`.  Instead you should use `map.get` to test it's existence (or map.contains).

```
    V local = _cache.get(key);
    if (local.equals(value) && !local.IsExpired()) {
        return;
    }
```

**2.** Instead of put you will want to replace, this is because a race condition can occur where the `if` can be evaluated as false by two or more threads in which one of the two (or more) threads will overwrite the other thread's puts.

What you can do instead is [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#replace%28K,%20V,%20V%29)

When all is said and done it could look like this

```
public void AddToCache(T key, V value) {
    for (;;) {

        V local = _cache.get(key);
        if(local == null){
            local = _cache.putIfAbsent(key, value);
            if(local == null)
                return;
        }
        if (local.equals(value) && !local.IsExpired()) {
            return;
        }

        if (_cache.replace(key, local, value))
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should return if replace() returns true.

Comment: also, you don't need to call get() again if putIfAbsent() returns non-null, you can use what you just got.  you only need a second get() call if replace fails.

Comment: @jtahlborn I was thinking about cleaning that up, i'll put something in.

Comment: It could have been swapped out for `while(true){`  But what you are trying to do is an atomic update.  There is the likelyhood of a race condition in which an update to the current value in the cache (as a result of multiple puts at the same time) can fail.  The `for(;;){` simple says "continue trying until you succeed".  for(;;) simply means, loop forever.

Comment: You can see if the `_cache.replace(key,local,value)` fails it will try again until a return statement is reached.

Answer (score 5):

Your code will throw an NPE if the key was not previously in the map.

Other than that, although this is a reasonable idea, it will not work in a "*concurrent*" environment. The reason the `putIfAbsent()` method was added was so that the map could manage the atomicity of the operation using whatever underlying support it is using to make the operations thread-safe. In your implementation, 2 different callers could end of stepping on each other (the first replaces an expired value with a new one, and the second immediately replaces the first new one with a second new one).

Comment: The fact about the concurrent situation cannot be pointed out often enough. :) +1