# what if we want to allow overwriting the values with putIFAbsent in concuurentHashMap?

Tags: java, concurrency

what if we want to allow overwriting the values by two different threads with putIFAbsent in concuurentHashMap?

Saying I have String key, String value1 and String value2 in my concurrent hash map and say I want to allow overwriting the values for the same key by two different threads. Do I need to have a loop ?

```
public insertCarefullyIntoMap(String key, value) {
    while(value != putIfAbsent(key,value)){}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486413/concurrenthashmap-put-vs-putifabsent

Comment: That post really dosen't address how to allow safe overwriting of the values for the same key in the concurrentHashMap.

Comment: I had given the link for the original question you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

The `put` function still works like normal - in fact, the Java documentation uses it to describe the behaviour of `putIfAbsent`:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, associate it with  the given value. This is equivalent to
>
> ```
> if (!map.containsKey(key))
>     return map.put(key, value);
> else
>     return map.get(key);
> ```
>
> except that the action is performed atomically.

So if you don't care whether the key already exists in the hashmap, then you can just put your value in unconditionally:

```
public insertCarefullyIntoMap(String key, String value) {
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

The only constraints with the `put` function are that both the key and the value must not be null.

Comment: I am looking for a difference between put and putIfAbsent in multiThreaded case

Comment: First thread to putIfAbsent will win, the other one will then just get the value, because the key is no longer absent. If you don't want that behaviour, just use the put method.

Comment: You can also have a look at the replace method. Replace will check against the old value of the key, and only if it matches, it will update the value of the key. Maybe that fits better to your requirements.

Comment: The name `ConcurrentHashMap` says it all - `put` behaves exactly as it would if you were using a normal HashMap, except that it may be slightly slower, because it is synchronized. If you care about the order in which things are put into the HashMap, then you need to synchronize _your_ code, so that you know the order in which threads are accessing the HashMap.

Comment: @dunni `replace` is also an atomic version of
`if (contains(key)) return put(key, value) else return null;`

Comment: @Andrew If i understand the Javadoc of replace correctly, it does a bit more (you give a third parameter, which represents the expected current value, and replace checks that with the actual current value, and only if it matches, it does the put).

Comment: Yes, there's multiple overloads - it would help if we were looking at the same one :)

Comment: Ah, just saw that there are two replace methods. I was referring to the one with the signature replace(K key, V oldValue, V newValue)

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson you raise a very important point about the order of execution. correct me if I am wrong so get operations overlap with put and remove so does that mean get doesn't guarantee I will always see the most recent value? also does java 8 concurrenthashmap still splits the map into buckets? I heard it does something different in java 8?

Comment: That's right - you may call _get_ in one thread, then a few milliseconds later, call _put_ from another. By chance, the second thread acquires the lock first, updates the value, and so the value you see is out of order to the calls you made. As for splitting into buckets - I'm not sure about the implementation details, maybe that's another question for SO?